# Entity Framework 4 Is it possible to read a connection string from another file rather than app.config?

Tags: entity-framework

I am new to EF using EF4 with Database First and generation taking place.
I have to place the connection string in a different config than the  app.config.

How can I do it? How can I bypass it?

I have a partial class of MyTextContext
and I have a method like this

```
   public static string GenerateConnectionString()
  {
     SqlConnectionStringBuilder sqlBuilder = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder();

     // Set the properties for the data source.
     sqlBuilder.DataSource = dbServer;
     sqlBuilder.InitialCatalog = dbName;
     sqlBuilder.UserID = "YOUR_USERNAME";
     sqlBuilder.Password = "YOUR_PASSWORD";
     sqlBuilder.IntegratedSecurity = false;

     // Build the SqlConnection connection string.
     string providerString = sqlBuilder.ToString();

     // Initialize the EntityConnectionStringBuilder.
     var entityBuilder = new EntityConnectionStringBuilder();

     //Set the provider name.
     entityBuilder.Provider = "System.Data.SqlClient";

     // Set the provider-specific connection string.
     entityBuilder.ProviderConnectionString = providerString;

     // Set the Metadata location.
     entityBuilder.Metadata = @"res://*/myTestModel.csdl|
                            res://*/myTestModel.ssdl|
                            res://*/myTestModel.msl";


     return entityBuilder.ToString();
  }
```

I have noticed that my EFModel.designer has a constructor like these:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes a new MyTestContext object using the connection string found in the 'MyTestContext' section of the application configuration file.
    /// </summary>
    public MyTestContext() : base("name=MyTestContext", "MyTestContext")
    {
        this.ContextOptions.LazyLoadingEnabled = true;
        OnContextCreated();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Initialize a new MyTestContext object.
    /// </summary>
    public MyTestContext(string connectionString) : base(connectionString, "MyTestContext")
    {
        this.ContextOptions.LazyLoadingEnabled = true;
        OnContextCreated();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Initialize a new MyTestContext object.
    /// </summary>
    public MyTestContext(EntityConnection connection) : base(connection, "MyTestContext")
    {
        this.ContextOptions.LazyLoadingEnabled = true;
        OnContextCreated();
    }
```

How can I use my "GenerateConnectionString" rather then EF reading from the app.config?

Thanks for any suggestions

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Did you try using the 2nd ctor overload?

```
public MyTestContext(string connectionString)
```

e.g

```
var ctx = new MyTestContext(GenerateConnectionString());
```

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb739017.aspx):

> The Entity Data Model tools generate a named connection string that is stored in the  application's configuration file. This named connection string can be supplied instead of the connectionString parameter when instantiating the ObjectContext class.

So in *theory*, it should use the one you supply (unless you use the parameterless constructor).

I've never tried this though (i don't use code generation, i hand craft everything).

Comment: It's my first go at EF and ultimately I will handcraft too.But I am building something new at the office and they told me to do it with EF.Nobody knows how to do it.You mention try 2nd overload.Where should that code go?In my partial class? Or in the class the call the context.

Comment: I have used ctx=new MyTextContext(GenerateConnectionString()) but cannot find my method eventthough is in the partial class

Comment: Can't find the method? Is is the same namespace? Does your partial class error if you leave off the partial keyword? Can you post the namespace/class declarations of both your partial class and code generated designer file? Another option could be to create a class deriving from MyTextContext, and put the `GenerateConnectionString` logic in that class, so the ctor for that deriving class could be `public MyDerivedTextContext() : base(GenerateConnectionString())`

Comment: And to answer your first question, yes - i would hide that method away somewhere, preferably in your partial class. It probably should be a private method, not public (at maximum it should be internal).

Comment: Hi,Thanks for your reply.It;s the same namespace and if I remove partial it does error.It was declared as public static GenerateConnectionString.Removed the static but obviosly still cannot do  var ctx=new MyTestContext(GenerateConnectionString()); I can do ctx.GenerateConnectionString but that will be too late.No

Comment: There must be something obvious wrong -hard to tell without the code. You've got a method in the same class which you cannot call, doesnt make much sense. :) Try putting it a static helper class? What error do you get when you try and call the method?